# confusion matrix results in CNN keras

Tags: python, keras, cnn, python-3.x

I am writing a code to classify images from two classes, dogs and cats. I wrote the below code, but always all the dogs images are classified as cats as shown in the confusion matrix.

Am I missing something in the code?

Note: I tried epochs up to 70, but got same results.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D,Activation,MaxPooling2D,Dense,Flatten,Dropout
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from IPython.display import display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix


classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),input_shape=(64,64,3)))
classifier.add(Activation('relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size =(2,2)))
classifier.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3)))
classifier.add(Activation('relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size =(2,2)))
classifier.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3)))
classifier.add(Activation('relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size =(2,2)))
classifier.add(Flatten())
classifier.add(Dense(64))
classifier.add(Activation('relu'))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.5))
classifier.add(Dense(1))
classifier.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
classifier.summary()
classifier.compile(optimizer ='rmsprop',
                   loss ='binary_crossentropy',
                   metrics =['accuracy'])
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale =1./255,
                                   shear_range =0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip =True)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

batchsize=32
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('/home/osboxes/Downloads/Downloads/dogs-vs-cats/train/',
                                                target_size=(64,64),
                                                batch_size= batchsize,
                                                class_mode='binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('/home/osboxes/Downloads/Downloads/dogs-vs-cats/test/',
                                           target_size = (64,64),
                                           batch_size = batchsize,
                       shuffle=False,
                                           class_mode ='binary')
history=classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                        steps_per_epoch =9000 // batchsize,
                        epochs = 30,
                        validation_data =test_set,
                        validation_steps = 4500 // batchsize)

Y_pred = classifier.predict_generator(test_set, steps=4500 // batchsize+1)
y_pred = np.argmax(Y_pred, axis=1)
print('Confusion Matrix')
print(confusion_matrix(test_set.classes, y_pred))
print('Classification Report')
target_names = test_set.classes
class_labels = list(test_set.class_indices.keys())   
report = classification_report(target_names, y_pred, target_names=class_labels)
print(report) 

# summarize history for accuracy
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
# summarize history for loss
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your line

```
y_pred = np.argmax(Y_pred, axis=1)
```

by:

```
y_pred = Y_pred > 0.5
```

You might need to flatten your Y_pred array beforehand.

Your classifier is returning a score between 0 and 1 defining how probable the image belongs to class 1.
When you call argmax on your prediction, it will always return 0, as there always is a single entry in your array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace this:

```
classifier.add(Dense(2))
```

because you have 2 class: cat & dog.

Comment: do you have a source for that claim. Usually binary classification in Keras has a output layer = 1. See this model for instance: https://github.com/Bixi81/Python-ml/blob/master/keras_pretrained_imagerec_binaryclass.py